# Biocircos Link track automation

Tags: r

I would like to automate BioCircos plot in R and here is my code. However, I am not able to link the tracks when I am using the full file.

Thank you in advance
KL

```
Input file

All_C1.txt

query   pos1    sub     pos2
AUSP_1  15147   AUSA_1  93903
AUSP_1  15147   AUSA_2  93903
AUSP_1  15182   AUSA_1  93938
AUSP_9  15204   AUSA_4  93960
AUSP_1  15228   AUSA_1  93984
AUSP_2  15242   AUSA_3  93998
AUSP_1  15263   AUSA_1  94019
AUSP_3  15264   AUSA_5  94021
AUSP_1  15285   AUSA_1  94042
AUSP_4  15287   AUSA_6  94044
AUSP_1  15301   AUSA_1  94058
AUSP_5  15309   AUSA_7  94066
AUSP_6  15313   AUSA_8  94070
AUSP_7  15319   AUSA_9  94076
AUSP_8  15320   AUSA_1  94077



library(BioCircos)
setwd("/PATH/TO/FILE")
data <- read.table("All_C1.txt")                                              
head(data)

myGenomeAus0 = list("AUSP_1" = 31248581,
                    "AUSP_2" = 31645086,
                    "AUSP_3" = 47108296,
                    "AUSP_4" = 29969644,
                    "AUSP_5" = 36443716,
                    "AUSP_6" = 26560673,
                    "AUSP_7" = 28486927,
                    "AUSP_8" = 29326496,
                    "AUSP_9" = 29774650,
                    "AUSA_1" = 31122193,
                    "AUSA_2" = 32101233,
                    "AUSA_3" = 46783639,
                    "AUSA_4" = 29229108,
                    "AUSA_5" = 36358360,
                    "AUSA_6" = 26077416,
                    "AUSA_7" = 27897604,
                    "AUSA_8" = 29233132,
                    "AUSA_9" = 30348868)

links_chromosomes_1 <- read.table("All_C1.txt")
V1 <- links_chromosomes_1[1]
#V1

links_pos_1 <- read.table("All_C1.txt")
V2 <- links_pos_1[2]
#V2

links_chromosomes_2 <- read.table("All_C1.txt")
V3 <- links_chromosomes_2[3]
#V3

links_pos_2 <- read.table("All_C1.txt")
V4 <- links_pos_2[4]

for (i in V1[1]){
#print (i)
  for (j in V2[1]){
#print (j)
    for (k in V3[1]){
#print (k)
      for (l in V4[1]){
#print (l)
    tracklist = BioCircosLinkTrack('myLinkTrack', i, j, j,
                                   k, l, l, genome = myGenomeAus0,
                                   maxRadius = 1, color = "black", width = "1.0em",
                                   displayAxis = TRUE, axisColor = "black", axisWidth = 0.5,
                                   axisPadding = 0, displayLabel = TRUE, labelColor = "black",
                                   labelSize = "1em")
      }
  }
  }    
}

BioCircos(tracklist, genome = myGenomeAus0, genomeFillColor = c("Spectral"),
          chrPad = 0.05, displayGenomeBorder = FALSE,
          genomeTicksDisplay = FALSE,  genomeLabelTextSize = "20pt", genomeLabelDy = 0)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: for (i in V1[1]){ for (j in V2[1]){ for (k in V3[1]){ for (l in V4[1]){
    tracklist = BioCircosLinkTrack('myLinkTrack', i, j, j, k, l, l, genome = myGenomeAus0, maxRadius = 1, color = "black", width = "1.0em", displayAxis = TRUE, axisColor = "black", axisWidth = 0.5, axisPadding = 0, displayLabel = TRUE, labelColor = "black", labelSize = "1em")
      }
  }
  }    
}